# Need help removing sink faucet cartridge!

Tags: faucet, sink, cartridge

I need help with two things:

1. Identifying which 3 holes inch faucet setup this is? Most of my house is Moen but this is not. I need to replace the soap dispenser and the spray handle, and cartridge.
2. Help me with specific instructions to remove the current cartridge, which I think would me identify the brand. I cannot get the current one out, and I’ve tried everything and don’t want to damage the faucet.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If these are Delta or Moen they may be under lifetime warranty.  You should check.  And then the replacement parts may come with instructions.  OTOH, assuming these have not all failed and you just want to refresh them, I suspect a brand new faucet set will be more economical and easier to install than replacing ALL of the spray head, cartridge, and soap dispenser.  And then you don't have to worry about damaging the old one.

Answer (score 0):

The soap dispenser will have a nut underneath the countertop that you will have to remove if replacing the entire unit with a new one. this is usually the best option. If replacing just the bottle and pump, check your supply store, they should be readily available. Bring in the old pieces.

To remove the cartridge, you'll need to unscrew that ring with the notches at 12, 3, 6 and 9 o'clock counterclockwise. That usually requires a spanner wrench easily obtained from your home store or plumbing supply store. Make an imprint on paper to get the right size. You might be able to use a slotted screwdriver at one of the notches and tap it with a hammer to loosen it up, then the cartridge pulls straight up.

The wrench will look something like this one for Delta faucets from Amazon. You'll have to check for one at your home store that fits your valve. I have made some by grinding out the excess material from an appropriate sized piece of metal conduit.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, can you share a link to what spanner wrench will work on this? The teeth at 12,3,6, and 9 are about a 1/4” deep recessed into the metal. I can’t find a tool that will work.

Comment: @Fla_guy23  See my edited answer.

Comment: @Fla_guy23 You can often use needle nose pliers to straddle the shaft in the center. Hold them vertically with the tips down and fit the tips into slots 180° apart. Twist to loosen the ring. If the ring won't cooperate then try a little penetrating oil, e.g. [PB B'laster](https://blasterproducts.com/product/pb-blaster-penetrant/), and let it sit for a while.